# considering if, else if, else statements when writing code (java)

Tags: java, if-statement

I wrote a program that takes the sum and range of three integers in Java. my program has several if statements for finding the range (distance between biggest and lowest integer). I was wondering if my "if statements" are the most efficient way to go about finding the range, and if not, then how could I make my "if statements" more efficient for my code, and what are some things I should consider when I am writing if and else if, and else statements in Java.

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter an integer value for n1");
    n1 = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The (integer) value for n1 is " + n1);

    System.out.println("Enter an integer value for n2");
    n2 = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The (integer) value for n2 is " + n2);

    System.out.println("Enter an integer value for n3");
    n3 = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The (integer) value for n3 is " + n3);

    sum = n1 + n2 + n3;
    System.out.println("The sum of n1+n2+n3 = " + sum);


    if(n3< n1 && n3<n2){
        if(n2<n1){
            maxRange = n1-n3;
        }
        else if (n2>n1){
            maxRange = n2-n3;
        }
    }

     if(n2<n3 && n2<n1){
        if(n3<n1){
            maxRange = n1-n2;
        }
        if(n3>n1){
            maxRange = n3-n2;
        }
    }

     if(n1<n2 && n1<n3){
        if(n2>n3){
            maxRange = n2-n1;
        }
        if(n3>n2){
            maxRange = n3-n1;
        }
     }


aMean = (n1+n2+n3)/3;

System.out.println("the arithmetic mean is : " + aMean);
System.out.println("The maxRange is :"+ maxRange);


}
```

}

Comment: @ParaSara Please try to write a switch statement to accomplish this.

Comment: Note that your code has not handled the case where two numbers are equal.  In fact, depending on how and where you declared `maxRange`, this program should not compile, because it is possible to go through the big block of `if` statements without ever setting `maxRange`, and then you use it.

Comment: @ajb I hadn't considered that, good catch. However, I did just run my code and input "2" for all the integer values (n1,n2,and n3) and my output for maxRange was 0

Comment: Try it with n1=3, n2=3, n3=2.  I bet it will still give you 0.  I think the reason it gave you 0 when you tried it was that `maxRange` was initialized to 0 and never set to anything else.

Comment: @ajb Ok, I see your point, thanks, I will fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In practice, for only three elements, the Math.max/Math.min solution is probably best. However, when you find yourself labeling variables with numbers like `n1`, `n2`, and `n3` you should at least consider using an array.

The array `n` in the following has index values `0` through `n.length-1`, that is, 0, 1, and 2. In order to keep the user interface unchanged, I added 1 to the index to get the element number, giving n1, n2, n3 in the messages.

`n[n.length-1]` is the last element of the array. After the sort, it is the element with the highest value, `n[0]` is the smallest element, and their difference is the range.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] n = new int[3];
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
      System.out.println("Enter an integer value for n" + (i+1));
      n[i] = in.nextInt();
      System.out.println("The (integer) value for n" + (i+1) + " is " + n[i]);
      sum += n[i];
    }

    System.out.println("The sum of n1+n2+n3 = " + sum);

    Arrays.sort(n);
    int maxRange = n[n.length - 1] - n[0];

    double aMean = (double)sum / n.length;

    System.out.println("the arithmetic mean is : " + aMean);
    System.out.println("The maxRange is :" + maxRange);
    in.close();
  }
}
```

I used `n.length` rather than 3 for flexibility. Consider the following program. It is refactored to separate out the array analysis code from obtaining the array elements. The data can now come from anywhere, and does not have to be three elements:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    analyze(new int[]{0,42,3,7,8});
    analyze(new int[]{4,3,10});
  }

  private static void analyze(int[] n) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
      System.out.println("The (integer) value for n" + (i+1) + " is " + n[i]);
      sum += n[i];
    }

    System.out.println("The sum is : " + sum);

    Arrays.sort(n);
    int maxRange = n[n.length - 1] - n[0];

    double aMean = (double)sum / n.length;

    System.out.println("the arithmetic mean is : " + aMean);
    System.out.println("The maxRange is : " + maxRange);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, totally understand why an array would be very useful, I do have a couple of questions.
 what does the (i+1) bit of code do (after "Enter an int value for n") 
also what does it do after "the int value for n is" @patricia

also, what does n.length do in the maxRange, and why are you subtracting 1 from it, then subtracting n[0]?

Comment: @IdanGelber I have added some more explanation for the points you asked about.

Answer (score 7):

You can avoid the if statements by using `Math.max` and `Math.min` :

```
int min = Math.min (n1,Math.min(n2,n3));
int max = Math.max (n1,Math.max(n2,n3));
int maxRange = max - min;
```